# Command line tool to crop PDF files

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, pdf, open-source

I am looking for an open source command line tool to crop PDF file just like we can do in Adobe Acrobat Pro. I have tried PdfTk, ImageMagick,  PyPDF, and GhostScript—all with no success so far.

Comment: Can you please describe what kind of cropping you can do with Adobe Acrobat pro? Because I do not have it and can therefore not tell what you are looking for.

Comment: In Adobe Acrobat Pro we can use the margin controls to crop the PDF. we can provide the value's for the top, bottom, right and left to crop

Answer (score 212, accepted):

I would suggest you take a look at [PDFcrop](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/pdfcrop.1.html).

If you wish to crop a pdf with left, top, right and bottom margins of 5, 10, 20, and 30 pt (points), then run

```bash
pdfcrop --margins '5 10 20 30' input.pdf output.pdf
```

in terminal. To actually crop something away, use negative values in the argument for crop. For example,

```bash
pdfcrop --margins '-50 -50 -50 -50' input.pdf output.pdf
```

crops 50 pts from the left, top, right, bottom (in this order).

If you run only the command `pdfcrop input`, it will output a file titled *input-crop.pdf* with zero margins. I find this very handy when including pdf illustrations in documents.

**Cropping multiple files**

Unfortunately, pdfcrop cannot crop multiple files at the time. It is however easy to write a script that will crop all pdfs in the folder the script is located in.

Create a new empty file, and call it `something.sh`. Open it with a text editor and insert the following:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for FILE in ./*.pdf; do
  pdfcrop "${FILE}"
done
```

Save it, and close. Then right click the file, go to *Properties > Permissions* and check the field *Allow executing file as program* (or run `chmod +x /path/to/something.sh` in terminal). Now close the dialog. Run the script by double clicking it and choosing *Run in Terminal*. And new, zero-margin cropped version of all pdfs with suffix *-crop* will now be printed in the folder. If you want margins or other things, you can of course just open the script and add arguments after `pdfcrop`.

Comment: Note that instead of specifying negative margins, one can also use `--bbox "<left> <bottom> <right> <top>"`. This allows to use the approach to determine the crop area described in my [answer below](http://askubuntu.com/a/592206/161463).

Comment: Is there a possibility of telling page number(which need to be cropped)?

Comment: I fear it's all or nothing. `pdfcrop --help` lists the available options. I cannot see anything there that would allow specifying a range of pages.

Comment: Comparing the size of PDFCrop's output to its input, it looks as if pdfcrop only modifies the bounding boxes. It doesn't remove data. So this approach would be unsuitable to make the pdf smaller, or hide information.

Comment: If you need the pages bigger use positive numbers like `--margins 5`; if you need them smaller use negative numbers like `--margins -5`.

Comment: Please be aware that hyperlinks in the PDF are not preserved.

Comment: In the simplest form, it also works with `pdfcrop input.pdf`. It is not necessary to specify margins, and an output file name will be chosen automatically.

Comment: To add to @Scz comment, above, in my version of `pdfcrop` (v1.33), the text string `-crop` is appended to the basename portion of the input filename.

Comment: pdfcrop is super slow (on pdf with 550 pages), and blew my file up to ten times the size. This worked much better for me: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42259/193342

Comment: can I crop on side, i.e. the left, only?

Comment: @FrederickNord, Yes. Use e.g. `-50 0 0 0` for margins.

Answer (score 66):

Thanks for Rasmus, you can install pdfcrop from texlive-extra-utils package:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-extra-utils
```

Then crop pdf files using pdf crop command as:

```
pdfcrop input.pdf output.pdf
```

use `--help` to see more amazing parameters like `--margins`

```
pdfcrop --margins 5 input.pdf output.pdf
```

which crop pdf with 5 bp from each side of page

Comment: The measurement is `bp`, which is slightly different from `pt`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/what-are-the-various-units-ex-em-in-pt-bp-dd-pc-expressed-in-mm.

Comment: For me pdfcrop inflated the file size from 300x (from 7MB to 2GB). I had to do `gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS="/ebook" -sOutputFile=output2.pdf output.pdf` afterwards, which fixed the file size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just wish texlive-extra-utils didn't require 87 dependencies (388 MB). I know, what does it matter in this day of terabytes of disk space, but still :)

Answer (score 24):

You can also crop PDF files simply using Ghostscript. I have written a small script to simplify the process (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6184547/1804173)):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 5 ]
then
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` <pdf-file> <x_min> <x_max> <y_min> <y_max>"
  echo "Notes:"
  echo " - all coordinates are absolute; no calculation of width/height necessary"
  echo " - use 'gv' to determine the coordinates"
  exit 65
fi

file="$1"
xmin="$2"
xmax="$3"
ymin="$4"
ymax="$5"

base="${file%.*}"
outfile="${base}_cropped.pdf"

echo "writing to: $outfile"

gs \
  -o $outfile \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
  -c "[/CropBox [$xmin $ymin $xmax $ymax] /PAGES pdfmark" \
  -f $file
```

In order to determine the coordinates for cropping, I use `gv`, which prints the coordinates of the mouse cursor using the same units as Ghostscript. For example, here I determine the minimum coordinates for x/y (the values in the upper left corner):

[image: crop1]

Now the maximum coordinates:

[image: crop2]

And finally, I run the script `pdf_crop_by_coordinates.sh test.pdf 45 429 38 419` producing a `test_cropped.pdf` which looks like that:

[image: result]

I have no idea though, how the Ghostscript solution compares to `pdfcrop` in terms of quality and correctness.

Comment: Flat out didn't work for me, surprising for a powerhouse like ghostscript. But pdfcrop did the job perfectly, and in one pass. The units are funky, need time to see if possible to config standard: pt, px or the like.

Comment: For me at least, the second gs command (the one after `echo "writing to: $outfile"`) may significantly decrease the resolution of any embedded images. Luckily, it may not be necessary, depending on what you do with your pdfs afterward.

Comment: If you have problems with spaces in file names, add following lines before `gs` call: `file=${file//\\}
outfile=${outfile//\\}`

Answer (score 24):

When I can't do something with pdftk, the next place I turn is [PDFjam](http://go.warwick.ac.uk/pdfjam), which is a command-line wrapper for the [pdfpages](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) LaTeX package (hence you also need that and a TeX distro installed). For help on how to use it, I recommend the regular help screen:

```
pdfjam --help
```

as the man page is sparse and the Web page concentrates on examples.

To crop a PDF, the command you need is something like this:

```
pdfjam --keepinfo --trim "10mm 15mm 10mm 15mm" --clip true --suffix "cropped" input.pdf
```

This will output a file called `input-cropped.pdf`. The order of the trims should be left, bottom, right, top, as per `\includegraphics` from [graphicx](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx).

To give an idea of how it compares with PDFcrop, I had cause to crop a quite fancy PDF recently. My original was 675 kB, my cropped version via PDFjam was 1.2 MB, while a version cropped via PDFcrop was 4.5 MB. While both PDFjam and PDFcrop stripped out the embedded hyperlinks and bookmarks, PDFjam with the `--keepinfo` option preserved the document properties (e.g. title, author, subject).

Comment: Note: this does not really remove the content that becomes off-screen from the PDF, only hides it. Same as what @init_js comments on in the top-scored answer.

Comment: This worked well for me.  I didn't realize at first that pdfcrop of `--margin '0'` even takes away the whitespace it finds and the non-zero margin adjusts from there.  My pdf had annoying crop marks on *most* of the pages so this pdfjam program was better for removing them.

Comment: Any way to keep annotations as well?  I found that they're gone after using either `pdfcrop` or `pdfjam`.

Comment: This solution also removes the bookmark/index/table of content.

Comment: @JanŻankowski sometimes that's exactly what you want, e.g. for printing into a bleed zone.

Answer (score 10):

[Briss](https://sourceforge.net/projects/briss/) is not command line, but worth a look at.

Comment: This is a fantastic software and it *retains* my annotations!!  The GUI lets you look at ALL pages of the PDF superimposed simultaneously!!

Answer (score 9):

The [pdfCropMargins](https://pypi.org/project/pdfCropMargins/) program is a command-line application to automatically crop the margins of PDF files.

This program depends on either the Ghostscript program or the pdftoppm program being installed (and locatable) on the system. And analyze the page images with PIL to find bounding boxes, using the threshold 191.

install using

> pip install pdfCropMargins

Run using

> pdf-crop-margins -v -s -u your-file.pdf

For help

> pdf-crop-margins -h | more

Answer (score 8):

If a graphical tool is also fine I would recommend `krop`: http://arminstraub.com/software/krop

Answer (score 4):

This may help you.
This is in accordance with the newer version of Ubuntu and life.
This is [Master PDF Editor](https://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor/). You can use it crop, add some stuff, etc.

Example:
This is before
[image: This is before]
This is after ctrl + k
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [pypdf script from this page](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576837-crop-pdf-file-with-pypdf/). But in the answer to [this stackexchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183479/cropping-a-pdf-using-ghostscript-9-01), there seem to be many options as well.

Comment: I am not able to get what the left top right bottom parameters are. are they points, inches, centimeters ?

Comment: @Rakesh: See my answer for an explanation of the parameters and how to determine them easily.

Answer (score 1):

PDF CPU is a good option:

```
pdfcpu crop '0 0 17' in.pdf out.pdf
```

https://pdfcpu.io/core/crop

Answer (score 0):

Using [pdfjam](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfjam) you can set any option which comes from the package [pdfpages](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages)  originally, and so you can set `--fitpaper true`, it should adapt the the paper size to fit to the (first) input file.

I had a case to combine multiple JPG into a PDF and adding metadata as well and trim it to incoming jpg size. This will work for equal sizes of input JPGs to be cropped well and have no white margins:

```bsh
# equal sizes of input images
pdfjam  Image_00001.jpg Image_00002.jpg Image_00003.jpg Image_00004.jpg Image_00005.jpg \
  --pdftitle   'My custom title' \
  --pdfsubject 'My custom subject' \
  --pdfkeywords 'keyword1; keyword2; keyword3; aso;' \
  --pdfauthor 'author1; author2;' \
  --fitpaper true --outfile 'Images_Combined.pdf'

pdfinfo 'Images_Combined.pdf' # testing results for meta data
# Title:           My custom title
# Subject:         My custom subject
# Keywords:        keyword1; keyword2; keyword3; aso;
# Author:          author1; author2;
# Creator:         LaTeX with hyperref
# Producer:        pdfTeX-1.40.22
# CreationDate:    Sun May  1 15:03:01 2022 CEST
# ModDate:         Sun May  1 15:03:01 2022 CEST
# …
```

Note: If you have *different* sizes of input JPG, it will fit the paper size to the first one and scale all remaining pages to be merged to the size of that first one, so some pages will have no white margins and some will have.

**Edit:** this was done from TeX Live 2021 with `pdfjam --version` 3.03 and package `pdfpages` from 2021/03/06