# How to crop all the pages of a PDF

Tags: 16.04, software-recommendation, pdf, editing

I saw this [Command line tool to crop PDF files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124692/command-line-tool-to-crop-pdf-files). Being ignorant couldn't understand it.
How can I crop all the pages with same dimension(except last and front)? This is precisely the [book](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/book/photonic-crystals-book.pdf). Also how to select the dimensions properly? That will be helpful.

Comment: @Stormvirux I saw that, and mentioned in the link in my question. Couldn't seem to grasp it completely

Comment: I've used PDFScissors, which (once you get it running) is easy to use and works well. It requires Java. https://sites.google.com/site/pdfscissors/

Comment: @NickWeinberg Is it for Ubuntu 16.04? Can you so some example of it?

Comment: Yes, it works on Ubuntu 16.04. I don't understand your second question (please be sure to read the webpage and watch the video about it to see if it answers your questions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may help you.
This is in accordance with the newer version of Ubuntu and life.
This is [Master PDF Editor](https://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor/). You can use it crop, add some stuff, etc.

Example:
This is before
[image: This is before]
This is after ctrl + k
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I personly love the tool Briss:
http://briss.sourceforge.net/

I used it to Crop pdfs to read on a Kindle.

[See a screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2wmN.jpg)

The Programm groups together pages with the same layout and superimposes them.
You are then able to select the part of all these pages you want in your pdf.
The programm also handle the order of the pages.
If needed you can crop one page in multiple pages.

If you want to exclude pages from the cropping process you can manually enter pages that souldn't be loaded when opening a new file.

hope I could help
gz